# How to read only certain number of entries from json file in jmeter?

Tags: java, json, post, jmeter, web-api-testing

I am sending json files as body. There are like 10k json files so I am using Directory Listing Config in jmeter plugin. While reading the json file I am using this:

```
${__FileToString(${file},,)}
```

to read file information. Json file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "urn:oaeignaeogin",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Player",
        "id": "aegaegaeg-aega-aegg-aegeag-aegaegeag",
        "text": {
          "status": "generated",
          "div": "<div xmlns=\"stuff"
        },
        "multipleBirthBoolean": false,
        "communication": [
          {
            "language": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "urn:437",
                  "code": "en-US",
                  "display": "English"
                }
              ],
              "text": "English"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Patient"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What do I do so that I only read entries upto 25 entries and then send it as body? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file contains only one `entry` element

[image]

If there are files with more than one `entry` and you need to send only first 25 you will need to parse the JSON using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), extract first 25 entries, re-build the JSON and overwrite the variable.

1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the request which you need to send
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File(vars.get('file')))
   if (json.entry.size() > 25) {
       json.entry = json.entry.take(25)
   }

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. Replace `${__FileToString(${file},,)}` in the "Body Data" tab of the "HTTP Request" Sampler

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)